# Is this possible with the Google Maps API to have an interactive map or a continent that you can put pins on?

Tags: canvas, google-maps-api-3, web, maps

Before I explain this this map is mean to be seen within a webpage. So we're talking about a web page/web app kind of view (not a native mobile OS app) or anything like that.

So I was wondering if it was possible to generate a silhouetted version of a continent, say, South America, that renders on the browser (either with canvas or whatever way) and then through a back end CRUD form to enter coordinates for a place within that continent and have pins automatically render on top of the silhouetted continent image in the right places (according to scale) so if you enter the coordinates for a place in Sao Paulo then the pin gets drawn on the map as closes as possible within the image of South America contained within these dimensions say: 400px by 700px.

Is this entirely possible or (even parts of it) though the Google Maps API? If so, could you point me to any appropriate examples or documentation?

EDIT: If I were to use their map to display South America, is it then possible to load their map so that South America always shows in its entirety within a container of 400px by 700px (or the closest possible rectangle with the right aspect ratio)?

Comment: If the user is entering coordinates, and you don't want localization data for those coordinates (i.e.: you just want to draw pins) then you **don't** need any map API at all, just a little math.

Otherwise, yes you could do stuff with the Google Maps API, but drawing your own map is a breach of their license agreement and they will cut your site off from using their API completely if they catch you doing that. [See section 10.1.1, item (g).](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_1)

Comment: It is true that you couldn't use the Google Maps data without Google Maps. However, you can do this without leaving Google Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you could do this. Either using

1. Map Styling to only show the continental outlines (http://goo.gl/stXu2)
   or
2. An custom map type to replace the map image with your own: http://goo.gl/fi9uVJ

In either case you probably would also want to use Polygons to render the borders of the country: http://goo.gl/2VLc3S